how can i add skip connection in this section of my code without create a new class for skip connection?
I want to add skip connection to this code in pytorch, how?
class Branch(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, channels, strides):
        super(Branch, self).__init__()
        
        self.conv_layer = nn.Sequential()
        for i in range(1, len(channels)):
            self.conv_layer.add_module(f'conv_{i}', nn.Conv2d(in_channels=channels[i-1], out_channels=channels[i], kernel_size=3, stride=strides[i-1], padding=(0, 1))),
            self.conv_layer.add_module(f'bn_{i}', nn.BatchNorm2d(channels[i])),
            self.conv_layer.add_module(f'relu_{i}', nn.ReLU())
            self.conv_layer.add_module(f'conv2_{i}', nn.Conv2d(in_channels=channels[i], out_channels=channels[i], kernel_size=3, padding='same')),
            self.conv_layer.add_module(f'bn2_{i}', nn.BatchNorm2d(channels[i])),
            self.conv_layer.add_module(f'relu2_{i}', nn.ReLU())

        self.projector = nn.LazyLinear(256)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv_layer(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), x.size(1) * x.size(2), x.size(3)).permute(0, 2, 1)
        x = self.projector(x)
        return x


I tried searching, but didn't see exactly what I wanted.

Default parameter skip_connection=False? not really sure what you are asking, please explain better your issue.

I mean, is there a ready-made instruction for it, or should we just add a special class for it and create it through it?
is this the correct way?
self.skip_connection = torch.nn.Identity()


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you want to add skip connections, you need to create a new nn.Module class for it. You also have to decide what layers you want in the skip connection. For example:
class SkipConv(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, stride, kernel_size, padding):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.conv = nn.Sequential(
                        nn.Conv2d(in_channels, 
                                  out_channels, 
                                  kernel_size=kernel_size, 
                                  stride=stride, 
                                  padding=padding
                                 ),
                        nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
                        nn.ReLU())
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = x + self.conv(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        return x

You would then swap the conv/bn/relu layers in your model with one of the SkipConv blocks.
